# HTML: one scrollbar for two frames

Tags: html, vb6, frames, frameset

I am having trouble having one scrollbar for two frames as seen in: [Two frames one scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237566/two-frames-one-scrollbar/4237591#4237591)

Below is my code:

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="151,*">
        <%if (something) then %>
            <FRAME SRC="UserQueue_Header.asp" NAME="UserQueue_Header" SCROLLING="no" NORESIZE />
            <FRAME SRC="UserQueue_Detail.asp" NAME="UserQueue_Detail" SCROLLING="yes" />
        <%else%>
            <FRAME SRC="UserQueue_Header.asp?SortField=<%=SortField%>&SortOrder=<%=SortOrder%>" NAME="UserQueue_Header" SCROLLING="no" NORESIZE />
            <FRAME SRC="UserQueue_Detail.asp?SortField=<%=SortField%>&SortOrder=<%=SortOrder%>" NAME="UserQueue_Detail" SCROLLING="yes" />  
        <%end if%>
</FRAMESET>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me only in Firefox. I had to set scrolling = yes for UserQueue_Header.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.frameready.js"></SCRIPT>
```

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
// Sync Header Frame with Detail Frame`
$.frameReady( function() {

    var ifr2 = $(window.parent.document.getElementsByName('UserQueue_Detail')[0].contentWindow);

   $(document).scroll( function(){

         ifr2.scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft());
    });
  },
  "UserQueue_Header"
);

// Sync Detail Frame with Header Frame
$.frameReady( function() {

    var ifr1 = $(window.parent.document.getElementsByName('UserQueue_Header')[0].contentWindow);

   $(document).scroll( function(){

         ifr1.scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft());
    });
  },
  "UserQueue_Detail"
);

});
```

This works both in IE and Firefox:

```
    <SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

```
$(window).load( function(){

  var ifr1 = $(window.frames[0]);
  var ifr2 = $(window.frames[1]);

  ifr1.scroll( function(){ 

     ifr2.scrollLeft(ifr1.scrollLeft());
  });

  ifr2.scroll( function(){

     ifr1.scrollLeft(ifr2.scrollLeft());
  });
});

<frameset>
    <frame src="test.html"/>
    <frame src="test.html"/>
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use frames, or only use an iframe for the header. And position the header using position:fixed; this way you get the same effect with frameset, namely a sticky header.

Comment: The header has to scroll along with the detail. I updated the full code.

Comment: What do you mean with scroll along? You mean it will stay at the top of the screen even when scrolling down. That is exactly what position:fixed does.

Comment: Ok. Both frames need a horizontal scroll bar because they span past the screen width. Since one frame is the header and the other is the detail, they both must scroll adjacently. I am thinking of placing the header and detail frames into one frame.

Comment: What are the widths of the header and the content? If they are the same my method will just work. The pages horizontal scrollbar will also scroll the header horizontally. Combining the vertical but keeping both horizontal scrollbars is just in no way possible.