# remove frame scrolling bar

Tags: html, frame

I designed a web page with frames. It is my homework so I must use frames.
In my page there are a lot of frames, and the inner frame has scrolling bar. I ned to remove it, how can i remove it?

This is my main.html code:

```
<frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="18%,*,18%" border="0" >
<!-- Navigational Bar -->
    <frame src="side.html" name="left" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
<!-- Interior Frame -->
    <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" rows="280,*" border="0">
        <frame src="header.html" name="middle" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
        <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="180,*" border="0">
            <frame src="left.html" name="anasayfa" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
            <frame src="anasayfa.html" name="mainframe" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
<!-- Interior Frame -->
    <frame src="side.html" name="right" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
```

This is my page outlook:

[image]

http://download.cnet.com/YouTube-To-MP3/3000-2071_4-75810474.html >youtube to mp3

Comment: There are several CSS tricks that can be user, but It needs test. Can you share a link or demo?

Comment: Here is my code files. You can dowload it. http://www.2shared.com/file/KbHG4YTT/site.html

Answer (score 3):

Just add to the main.html in lines with frames:

```
scrolling="no"
```

so the result is:

```
<frame scrolling="no" src="left.html" name="anasayfa" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" >
```

This is your main.html result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Webpage, design, yumakli" />
<meta name="description" content="Yumakli koyu web sayfasi" />
<style type = "text/css">
frame{
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</style>
<script></script>
</head>
<div style="width:5000; height:5000;">
<frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="18%,*,18%" border="0" >
<!-- Navigational Bar -->
    <frame src="side.html" name="left" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize"  scrolling="no">
<!-- Interior Frame -->
    <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" rows="280,*" border="0">
        <frame src="header.html" name="middle" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize"  scrolling="no">
        <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="180,*" border="0">
            <frame src="left.html" name="anasayfa" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
            <frame src="anasayfa.html" name="mainframe" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
<!-- Interior Frame -->
    <frame src="side.html" name="right" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize"  scrolling="no">
</frameset>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: In this case, I can not see the whole page. I need to remove the inner scrolling bar. The whole page can contain tha bar instead of the inner frame.

Comment: That is another problem post another question. Also you didn't had the scroll in the main page to begin with. This question is solved.

Comment: thanks but I have already known to use scrolling, it can not solve my problem actually. Maybe, I must mention the case in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Just set  `overflow: hidden;` on the object:

```
#objectID {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

***Note:*** Change `objectID` for with your object id.

You may also try:

```
frame{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It may work... wouldn't hurt if you try :)

Good luck!

Comment: It does not change anything :(

Comment: Can you provide me a link to your site so i could use firebug and find a way?
thanks.

Comment: Here is my code files. You can dowload it. Thanks 2shared.com/file/KbHG4YTT/site.html

Comment: ok so all you need to do is add: 'scrolling="no"' on each 'frame' tag. 
it is as easy as it sounds. 
but notice: you would get the full width of the items inside the frame (that's why there is a scroll bar)
hope i help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `scrolling` attribute to your frame and set the value to `no`.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_frame_scrolling.asp

Edit:

Another option is to [add another frameset](http://www.webxpertz.net/forums/showthread.php/257-How-do-I-get-two-frames-to-scroll-off-one-scroll-bar-i-e-act-as-if-one-page#post5088) around the ones you have currently created.

Found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237566/two-frames-one-scrollbar) and adapted to you.

file index.html:

```
<html>
    <frameset rows="1,480" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes">
        <FRAME SRC="javascript:<HTML></HTML>" NAME="dummy" FRAMEBORDER="NO" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO">
        <FRAME SRC="main.html" NAME="scrollcontent" FRAMEBORDER="NO" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" NORESIZE SCROLLING="yes">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

file main.html

```
<html><frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="18%,*,18%" border="0" >
<!-- Navigational Bar -->
    <frame src="side.html" name="left" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
<!-- Interior Frame -->
    <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" rows="280,*" border="0">
        <frame src="header.html" name="middle" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" SCROLLING="NO">
        <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="180,*" border="0">
            <frame src="left.html" name="anasayfa" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" SCROLLING="NO">
            <frame src="anasayfa.html" name="mainframe" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize" SCROLLING="NO">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
<!-- Interior Frame -->
    <frame src="side.html" name="right" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" frameborder="NO" border="0" noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
</html>
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: But in this case, I can not the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so all you need to do is add: `scrolling="no"` on each `'frame'` tag.

It is as easy as it sounds.

**But notice:** you would get the full width of the items inside the frame (that's why there is a scroll bar)

Hope i help :)

Answer (score 0):

in main page write

```
frame::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    display: none;
}

 /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
frame ,frameset {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
 }
```

go to frame page

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar 
   {
       display: none;
   }

 /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
body 
{
     -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
     scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
 }
```