# Manage multiple scroll with only one bar

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, user-experience

I'm building a Web Application in which I have multiple scrollbar, but I want to manage it into one.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-mVch5dDBkOQThXcGV0LVN6LWs/view?usp=drivesdk

Do you know some library or a way to handle this?

One example of this behavior is: when you create a Page on Wordpress, in the past there was 2 scrolls, one for the Editor and other for the page. But now, both are manage by only one Scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two frames one scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237566/two-frames-one-scrollbar)

Comment: This solution Apply only with two frames, but what about having a frame, a div with overflow: scroll, and the scroll of the page ?